# swift build: warning: '--product' cannot be used with the automatic product 'ProductName'; building the default target instead

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I have a `Package.swift` manifest as follows:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.4
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "long-package-name-ios",
    defaultLocalization: "en",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v14),
        .macOS(.v10_15)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "PackageName",
            targets: ["PackageName"]),
        .library(
            name: "PackageNameImproved",
            targets: ["PackageNameImproved"]),
        .library(
            name: "PackageNameUI",
            targets: ["PackageNameUI"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(
            name: "PackageLib",
            url: "ssh://apple.com/packagelib.git",
            .upToNextMinor(from: "1.2.3")
        )
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "PackageName",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "PackageLib", package: "PackageLib"),
            ],
            path: "PackageName"),
        .target(
            name: "PackageName",
            dependencies: [
                "PackageName",
                .product(name: "PackageLib", package: "PackageLib"),
            ],
            path: "PackageNameImproved"),
        .target(
            name: "PackageNameUI",
            dependencies: [
                "PackageNameImproved",
            ],
            path: "PackageNameUI")
    ]
)
```

**Package Manifest summary:**

- 3 targets
- 1 target depends on the other one
- Only `PackageName` is compatible with macOS, the other ones are iOS-only

**Build commands**

Building `long-package-name-ios-Package`(builds all targets within the package) for iOS:

> swift build -Xswiftc "-sdk" -Xswiftc "$(xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator
> --show-sdk-path)" -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "arm64-apple-ios15.0-simulator"
>
> [137/137] Build complete!

Now trying to build just the `PackageName` for macOS:

> swift build -Xswiftc "-sdk" -Xswiftc "$(xcrun --sdk macosx
> --show-sdk-path)" --product "PackageName"
>
> [1/1] Planning buildwarning: '--product' cannot be used with the
> automatic product 'PackageName'; building the default target instead

And it proceeds with building the default target `long-package-name-ios-Package` for the macOS platform which obviously fails due to inability to import, e.g. UIKit or any other iOS-only framework.

**Question**

How can I specify to build only `PackageName` for the macOS platform? I'm open to creating an Xcode Package, Schemes and other different configurations, but the end goals should be to:

1. Integrate `long-package-name-ios-Package` (all targets) for iOS only
2. Integrate `PackageName` for macOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: While my original answer makes the error go away, it is not possible to actually import the library into the plugin. (It fails to compile with a "no such module" error.) This [seems](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-depend-upon-packageplugin-from-a-library-target/59600/5) to be intended behavior.

---

The "automatic product" in the error refers to the fact that the `PackageName` has no configured library type. If you configure its type (either `dynamic` or `static`), the error goes away and the target can be built:

```
.library(
  name: "PackageName",
  type: .dynamic,
  targets: ["PackageName"]
)
```